# Method does the right thing but it doesn't use method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

This might be an impossible question to answer but i will try to provide you with a lot of information so that you might know the problem and maybe you have had the same problem before.

I have a form that i serialize with this method:

```
//Sends a serialized string with all form keys from DementiaPrototype to RiskScore-view
$(document).on("click", "#btnsubmit", function () {
  if (validateForm() == true) { //a method for validating the form
    if (validatepersonid() == true) { //a method for validating the form
      if(validatenr() == true){ //a method for validating the form
        $("#PersonBMI").removeAttr('disabled');
        $.ajax({
          url: "/Home/RiskScore",
          type: "post",
          data: $("form").serialize(),
          success: function(result) {
            $('.content-wrap').html(result);
            //calls the functions that animates the thermometer on page loaded
            countScore();
            countScores();
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

the two methods after sucess countScore(); and countScores(); will take lot's of input values and from the form and do some calculating and then show it in a thermometer on the next page. They booth look almost the same except some different use of textboxes. The problem is that countScores() does what it should but i can't debugg it. countScore() does nothing and i can't debugg that either. The way i can't debugg it is that it just don't use the method and don't go through my debuggs. It's very strange and i just can't solve the problem :S No one on my company knows what is going on. I have deleted all cache so that can't be the problem(If it could have been).

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but you might want to replace three if's with one single `if(validateForm() && validatepersonid() && validatenr())`.

Comment: what do you mean by you cant debug it ? if you make a console.log inside both methods will they both not be displayed ? maybe you should serve the javascript in a $(window).load(function(){})  inside the html of the response, not inside the sucess function, is your two methods inside an external js file ? this is the way i usually do

Comment: i will set debugg places where it should stop but the methods is not used. But at the sametime one of the methods does what it should do so it has to be inside the method in some way.

Comment: You really need to take this back to the basics - start with a `console.log` on the success (removing any other code). Once you are happy with that, start re-introducing each line of code in the callback until you discover which one introduces the problem.

Comment: I solved my problem by spamming out console.log all over my code :P But i still think it's strange that i couldn't debugg the method and find the error that way?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you cancel the default action of the form to prevent the browser from redirecting away:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnsubmit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    ... your code comes here
});
```

Comment: It is the argument of the anonymous function passed to your click handler: `$(document).on("click", "#btnsubmit", function (e) {` <-- here's the `e`. You could of course pick whatever name you like. It represents the event that is passed by jQuery when invoking your anonymous callback. Alternatively you could `return false;` from your callback.

Comment: Is the AJAX request being sent? What does the server respond to? Analyze the AJAX request in FireBug to see why it might be failing.